# Fast JPEG scaling to half or a fourth in the transform domain

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, libjpeg

I'm under the impression that JPEG to JPEG scaling to 1/2 or 1/4th be very fast and high quality and even a smaller memory footprint when done in the transform domain (i.e. never decompressed).  Assuming this is correct, how can I do this with libjpeg?  Also, does an anti-aliasing filter need to be applied using this method?

(If it helps write a clearer response, I have a lot of experience with 1D DFTs)

Comment: If you are changing the image dimensions, this will change the number of MCUs. I can't conceive of any way to extract rows/cols from the frequency domain and have them work correctly in the spatial domain. You will need to decompress and recompress the image. One special case which could work is to take an image with color subsampling in both directions (4:2:0) and convert it to 4:4:4. This way you will only need to decode/scale/recode the Y component and leave the Cr/Cb unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

One of libjpeg's decompression parameters is a scale factor M/N where N is the source DCT size (usually 8).  M can be 1 to 16, so it should handle your requirements, and it seems likely that the scaling is done in transform space (check the source to be sure).

I don't have any idea how well this works as far as image quality.

Comment: I've seen that, but I want the final output to be compressed and it wasn't clear to me if you can skip decompression altogether.  I'll double check the source when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you may skip decompression completely.

The last step of JPEG is Huffman or Arithmetic Encoding. And this step definitely should be undone before scaling.

Comment: I found some code from the FreeImage project that seems to extract the quantization tables after the huffman encoding for lossless transformations, I'm working with that to see if that's what I need.   The libjpeg API is sort of confusing and slightly misleading about the steps that need to be taken, at least to me anyways.